# How to install Cassandra

Tags: software-installation, tar, cassandra

I have downloaded dsc-cassandra-2.2.4-bin.tar.gz from http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/ . How do I install it?

Comment: See that website: "Step 4: Review Installation Guides / Full Documentation": http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/install/installDeb.html

Answer (score 0):

tar -zxvf dsc-cassandra-2.2.4-bin.tar.gz to extract the tarball and follow this [LINK](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_installation.htm) for step by step installation tutorial

Comment: That website has clear instructions for using "apt-get". No need for the "tar.gz".

Answer (score 0):

The [DataStax website](https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/cassandra) that you linked to in your question no longer provides the DataStax Community Edition or the DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra. The easiest way to install Cassandra in Ubuntu is by installing the Cassandra snap package.

---

### How to install Cassandra snap package

Cassandra distributed database is a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The current stable version of the cassandra snap package is 3.7 and the edge version is 3.10-SNAPSHOT. To install cassandra run this command:

```
sudo snap install cassandra   
sudo snap connect cassandra:mount-observe
```

The cassandra snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.

You can check on the status of the cassandra service with:

```
systemctl status snap.cassandra.cassandra.service
```

If you were able to successfully start Cassandra, check the status of the cluster:

```
cassandra.nodetool status
```

In the output, `UN` means it's Up and Normal:

Set a custom configuration:

```
cat cassandra.yaml | sudo /snap/bin/cassandra.config-set cassandra.yaml
```

Commands:

- `cassandra.config-get`
- `cassandra.config-set`
- `cassandra.env-get`
- `cassandra.nodetool`

Answer (score 0):

You can also download cassandra.deb file and run command "dpkg -i cassandra.deb" to install it.

to run it : service cassandra start

to stop it: service cassandra stop

to get status: service cassandra status or nodetool status